# Factory_Girl not generating unique records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sequence, factory-bot, uniqueidentifier

I'm converting my application over to use factories instead of fixtures with Factory_Girl_Rails.  I have the following factory defined:

```
factory :requirement do
  sequence(:reqTitle) {|t| "Test Requirement #{t}"}
  ignore do
    categoryName " "
    categoryAbbr " "
 end

  reqText "This is a test general requirement for the purpose of, um, testing things"
  status "Approved"
  factory :reqWithCat do
    category
  end
  factory :reqWithNamedCat do
    category {create(:category, catName: categoryName, catAbbr: categoryAbbr)}
  end
  factory :reqFromUserRequirement do
    user_requirement
  end
end
```

Then, in the setup section, I run the following snippet:

```
(0..5).each do |x|
      requirement = create(:reqWithCat)
      requirement.ind_requirements {|ir| [create(:ind_requirements)]}
end
(0..5).each do |x|
    create(:reqWithNamedCat, categoryName: "User Interface", categoryAbbr: "UI")
end
```

However, my tests are failing, apparently because records aren't being created (for instance, the index test on the requirements controller tells me that there 0 records returned when there should be 10).  I run the tests in debug mode, and discover that every requirement created has the exact same id value.  Also, each record has the same sequence value.

I believe the duplicate records are failing to save, which is why I'm getting a 0 return.  However, I can't see what I've set up incorrectly.  What am I missing here?

Comment: The fact that you're being told you have 0 records as opposed to 1 record makes me think you may not have a duplicate record problem. This may be a silly question, but have tried calling `FactoryGirl.create` in all the cases you're currently calling `create`? Also, your loops could be more succinctly labeled as `5.times do ... end`, you don't need a block argument as far as you've shown us here.

Comment: Not necessarily a silly question.  I had called include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods, but that doesn't mean it was working.  Unfortunately, I still get 0 records returned.

Comment: Thanks for the 5.times recommendation.  It is cleaner looking.

Comment: Ok, next question. I've never seen nested factories like that before. Are you trying for inheritance, or is there another usage for this kind of implementation?

Comment: I have many to many relationships - for instance between requirement and category, so this is supposed to work for that purpose.  I may try and drop back to creating basic requirements just to see if I can get that working.

Comment: I've now made everything very simple, with just a build of the requirement, and no longer creating any associate records.  It appears as if the records are not being saved in the database.  The ID field remains the same on every record creation event.

Comment: As it turns out, the problem doesn't appear to be with the requirements factory, but the user factory.  The role is not being created properly.  I'll update once I do more research.

Comment: The problem definitely is in the user creation process.  The role associated with the user doesn't get created properly.  The factory works in the Rails console, but doesn't save the record when run in code.  I'll post back the results of this if I can ever figure it out.

Comment: Is that what the `user_requirement` call is for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once I fixed the user factories to create the related many properly, I then discovered that I had written this factory incorrectly based on the way I was defining scopes in my models.  Once that was fixed, the "broken" test began working.